# Rails stylesheet not loading on heroku (production mode)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

my stylesheets stopped loading on heroku (production mode only, everything works fine in local).

Here is the error message on heroku logs

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-cdff05ced6e18e533fc2f71d065b63f48ce16d3045406917ed854476a7eb1702.css")
```

and indeed when I run

```
heroku rake assets:precompile
```

Other files gets precompiled

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rb-readline-0.5.3/lib/readline.rb:458: warning: already initialized constant Readline::HISTORY
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rb-readline-0.5.3/lib/readline.rb:486: warning: already initialized constant Readline::FILENAME_COMPLETION_PROC
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rb-readline-0.5.3/lib/readline.rb:517: warning: already initialized constant Readline::USERNAME_COMPLETION_PROC
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rb-readline-0.5.3/lib/readline.rb:523: warning: already initialized constant Readline::VERSION
I, [2017-04-17T09:41:44.957818 #4]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/application-f295a8fe23711032f76515a85070c9a4a7195e35bb2ea56572a87cab10734aef.js
I, [2017-04-17T09:41:44.958361 #4]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/application-f295a8fe23711032f76515a85070c9a4a7195e35bb2ea56572a87cab10734aef.js.gz
I, [2017-04-17T09:41:50.103993 #4]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/application-e86e4356a42c5e1f39646b26c890239ee4734ecd3a9a5e4214aea2a68d0e4509.css
I, [2017-04-17T09:41:50.104211 #4]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/application-e86e4356a42c5e1f39646b26c890239ee4734ecd3a9a5e4214aea2a68d0e4509.css.gz
```

There are many posts on this topics and right now this is what I have on my production.rb file after several unsuccessful other attempts.

```
config.serve_static_files = true
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
config.assets.compile = true
```

Let me know if you have any idea. Thanks.

Comment: set config.assets.compile = false in production.rb and try the same steps. I guess the precompile happens every time the website is loaded because of the above configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run following command to your local machine:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

then push all generated & manifest file to heroku.